# How to clean or update sbt staging directory where remote repositories are downloaded to?

Tags: sbt

I've got a module `commonModule` that sits in a GitHub repository that's referenced by other modules using the following:

```
lazy val commonModule = ProjectRef(uri("github url"), "common-module")
```

The issue is that, if some codes are changed in the `common-module` module, `~/.sbt/0.13/staging/common-module` local directory is not `git update`'d.

What I can do is manually remove it to make it recreated so it can have the latest code, but it is not very good for the CI build.

Is there any sbt command I can use to clean or update staging directories?

Answer (score 1):

There's no command to clean or update the staging directory of a remote git repository - see the issue [#1284 Managed dependencies from Git not updated](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1284).